# How my client can see my team geoLocation from their geo location in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am pretty new in development of an Android application, my task is, i have to show the all team members on google maps and our customer will see out team on google map so if any team member will be near from their geo location, customer will contact to the team member and team member will server the service.

I don't know how to start work on this task, whatever i had idea i designed a mobile page. as attached image.[image: In this image black dots are our team member who are in field to server]

Please help me out how & what to do for start working on it.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic simple apporch you would need to do the following:

1.Save the location(Latlong)values in the server.So,individual user location will be saved in the server

2.In the customer program or app ,the entire list of team location will be downloaded from the server via an Api.Also, let it refreash on a timely basis to get the updated data